# 'Broken Record' Coding Challenge

Tags: python, strings, python-2.x, interview-questions

I was asked to complete a coding challenge for an interview. The challenge being to write a test function to check whether or not a string was a `broken record`. A `broken record` is defined as a string that contains a sequential repeated substrings. For example:

```
# These are broken records
"This is is a broken record"
"This is a is a broken record"
"This is a broken record. This is a broken record."

# These are not broken records
"This is not is a broken record"
"This is a is This"
"This is a broken record. This is not a broken record."
```

This is the code that I was able to come up with (Python 2.7). Any criticisms, improvements, or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
# Author: Jeremiah Zucker
# brokenRecord.py
# A small module to test whether a substring is repeated 
# immediately, like a broken record

def brokenRecord(sent):
   if sent == "": # Use defualt string if empty
      sent = "This is a a is This"
   print("Determining if broken record: %s" % sent)

   arr = sent.split(" ")

   # Create count array for the sentence
   carr = [0] * len(arr)
   for i in range(0,len(arr)):
      carr[i] = arr.count(arr[i])

   # For each element in the array, try to find the
   # repeat if one is possible
   for i in range(0,len(arr)):
      if carr[i] > 1 and findRepeat(arr, i):
         print("Is a broken record at %d!" % i)
         return
   print("Not a broken record.")

def findRepeat(arr, i):
   beg = arr[i]
   j = i

   # Find all other indices of 'beg'
   others = []
   while beg in arr[j+1:]:
      j = arr[j+1:].index(beg) + j + 1
      others.append(j)

   # For all other indices of 'beg'
   for j in others:
      # Get both substrings
      lenRep = j - i
      try:
         rep = arr[i:j]
         rep2 = arr[j:j+lenRep]
      except IndexError:
         continue

      # Are they equal?
      if rep == rep2:
         # print(rep)
         # print(rep2)
         return True

   # Nope
   return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
   # print usage
   print("brokenRecord.py")
   print("To use, type a string and hit ENTER.")
   print("If no string is provided, the default string will be used.")

   # do until ctrl+c
   while True:
      try:
         brokenRecord(raw_input("\nString: "))
      except KeyboardInterrupt:
         print("\nThanks for testing!")
         break
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First impressions matter in interview coding situations.  My first thought is: There's a lot of code.  And interviewers usually don't like to wade through a lot of code.  For you, as a candidate, that may be a sign that you are taking the wrong approach.

Function names should be `lower_case_with_underscores` [as specified in PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) coding conventions.

There should be a function that accepts a string and returns either `True` or `False`.  Your `brokenRecord()` function…

> ```
> def brokenRecord(sent):
>    if sent == "": # Use defualt string if empty
>       sent = "This is a a is This"
>    print("Determining if broken record: %s" % sent)
>    …
>    print("Not a broken record.")
> ```

… incorporates all kinds of junk that make it not reusable:

- A weird `if sent == "": sent = "This is a a is This"` special case.  Such 
  a special case should be moved out into your testing mechanism — the caller, or, better yet, a [doctest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html).
- Printing diagnostics.  Again, such code should be done by the caller.
- Not returning any useful value, making it hard for the caller to know what happened.

Catching `IndexError` to recover from out-of-bounds array access is poor style.

In your main loop, you could eliminate the `break` by swapping the `try` and `while`.

```
# do until ctrl+c
try:
   while True:
      brokenRecord(raw_input("\nString: "))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
   print("\nThanks for testing!")
```

### Suggested solution

If I, as an interviewer, had asked this question, I would be hoping for a completely different kind of answer.  String analysis is much more easily done using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping).  In particular, you need this feature:

> Backreferences in a pattern allow you to specify that the contents of an earlier capturing group must also be found at the current location in the string. For example, `\1` will succeed if the exact contents of group 1 can be found at the current position, and fails otherwise. Remember that Python’s string literals also use a backslash followed by numbers to allow including arbitrary characters in a string, so be sure to use a raw string when incorporating backreferences in a RE.
>
> For example, the following RE detects doubled words in a string.
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> p = re.compile(r'(\b\w+)\s+\1')
> >>> p.search('Paris in the the spring').group()
> 'the the'
> ```

```
import re

def is_broken_record(s):
    """
    Check whether a string contains sequential repeated substrings.

    >>> is_broken_record("This is is a broken record")
    True
    >>> is_broken_record("This is a is a broken record")
    True
    >>> is_broken_record("This is a broken record. This is a broken record.")
    True

    >>> is_broken_record("This is not is a broken record")
    False
    >>> is_broken_record("This is a is This")
    False
    >>> is_broken_record("This is a broken record. This is not a broken record.")
    False
    """
    return bool(re.search(r'\b(.+)\s+\1', s))
```

Comment: Holy cow. I did not know about regex backreferences. That's so much simpler. Also, thanks for the `doctest` reference. I had always just thought those were extensive comments. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note that there is probably a typo in the function. Should have been as in the answer above `return bool(re.search(r'\b(\w+)\s+\1', s))`. Otherwise 'This is not a not abroken record' would yield `True`

Answer (score 2):

@200_success solution is great. In case you still want to make the comparison in nested loops I think it is cleaner to have it all in one simple function. The following is just such nested loops function. The hardest part is formulating the indices correctly.

```
def brokenrecord(sentence):
    words = sentence.split(' ')
    n = len(words)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(int((n-i)/2)):
            if words[i:i+j+1] == words[i+j+1:i+2*j+2]:
                return True
    return False
```